# Group Action by Inversion

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I was reading through the chapter on Cohomology in Dummit and Foote, and I constantly came across the term "action of the cyclic group $C_{2}$ on $G$ by inversion". What does this refer to? Is it an action such that:

$g \cdot e= g \hspace{0.2cm} \forall g \in G \quad g \cdot x=g^{-1} \hspace{0.2cm} \forall g \in G$

For $x$ being the non-trivial element in $C_{2}$? This is a very simple question, but I'm not so sure on what is the correct terminology here.

Comment: That's exactly it.

Answer (score -1):

In general, an action of $C_n$ on an object $G$ of a category (for example a group) is a homomorphism $C_n \to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$, which, by the universal property of $C_n = \langle x : x^n = 1 \rangle$, amounts to an element $\sigma \in \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ with $\sigma^n=1$. Therefore, one usually only specifies $\sigma$. The action is then $x^k \mapsto \sigma^k$.

Comment: What is the universal property of $C_n$? Searching I can only find the universal property of free groups, but I can't make the connection (if there is one to be made).

Comment: Every group presentation is really a universal property. In this case, $C_n$ classifies $n$-torsion elements, i.e. $\hom(C_n,G) \cong \{g \in G : g^n=1\}$ (naturally in $G$).